# Unable to initialize chrome driver with chrome driver 85 and chrome browser version 85

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When executing any Test Script. chrome driver is not getting initialized and throwing null exception in visual studio 2019

Execute any selenium UI test case against goolge.com

here is the error I am getting in my visual studio 2019

```
  Message: 
    Test method  threw exception: 
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    TestCleanup method  threw exception. System.NullReferenceException: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83 (SessionNotCreated)
```

Detailed steps to reproduce the behavior:

Expected behavior
chrome driver should be initialized in visual studio 2019

Test script or set of commands reproducing this issue
Please provide a test script to reproduce the issue you are reporting, if the
setup is more complex, GitHub repo links with are also OK.

Environment
OS: Windows 10
Browser: Chrome Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Browser version: Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Browser Driver version: ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87
Language Bindings version: C# Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Is driver in same folder ans the c# executable? I think following line is failing : driver = new ChromeDriver(currentPath, options);

Comment: See the error logs, it mentions that **This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83 (SessionNotCreated)**. So I think you have to upgrade the chrome driver or downgrade the chrome version.

Comment: @jdweng yes, It is using the current directory which is my user folder. I debugged it and the path is showing correctly.

Comment: @DilipMeghwal  I have the latest version of chrome browser version 85 and chrome driver version 85. I am unable to upload my screenshot here. It won't let me.

Comment: Are you manually adding chromedriver? Why are you not using nuget?

Comment: @RichEdwards I am using nuget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved = nuget package was not updating the chrome driver even though it was showing as the latest version. nuget was showing that latest chrome driver is update. but in the bin folder. it was actually the older version. I had to reboot my visual studio and uninstall the nuget package and reinstalling fixed the issue. thanks for the help